# What can an attacker do with an OpenID token

Tags: attack-vector, openid

Say an attacker had access to a list of OpenID tokens, what could the attacker leverage with that to access a system?

Would they need to have another piece of information, MITM? Or can they just use that to authenticate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token essentially is what gives you access for a certain amount of time. So, yes an attacker could use the token to access a system.